# Error 404 on page reload with vue3 routing

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

**Problem**

When I hit reload on a route, e.g /installer, in vue3.js I get the following error:

[image: Error]

**Code**

I use the [Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) with the following setup:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
```

**Additional Information**

(I don't use createWebHashHistory to get rid of the hashtags in url)

I also get this error when I go to the route, e.g. /installer, directly and not via link.

**Question**

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to do with your server configuration, read through [this section from the docs](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode):

> ... Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access https://example.com/user/id directly in their browser. Now that's ugly. Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in. Beautiful, again!

[The section below it](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) gives different examples for different servers.

---

It suggests using the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) package for an Express server, but I've always just used this which works fine:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx, I suggest add this line to the nginx config file:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

refer to: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#apache